# Can I use the past progressive here?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, continuous-aspect, progressive-aspect

Let's say I am at the train station and I missed the train, I still see it driving off. I would naturally say to myself: 'Damn, that was the train I was hoping to get.' Would that be wrong? If not, why is the past progressive used here? I have been taught that you use the past progressive when you are either talking...

- about a longer action that was interrupted by a shorter action
- about actions that were happening at the same time
- about an action that was in process at a specific time in the past

However, my sentence doesn't follow any of the rules above (at least I don't see that).

Another sentence that I can't gramatically explain...
Context: You told your friend David that Fred would not behave good when he is drunk before going to a party at which Fred gets drunk and then behaves bad. Later you say to David 'See? That's what I was talking about.' What's the grammatical explanation of this?

Can anyone give me a rule why these sentences work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you insist on understanding past progressive through the lens of those three rules, consider that you were hoping to catch the train ("a longer action") but then missed it ("a shorter action").

Comment: I was hoping someone would ask this question! I could have said *"I hoped someone would ask!"*, but I think the past progressive implies a stronger connection to the present (I'd been in a *continuous* state of desire/expectation right up until I read this post; it wasn't just something I felt briefly some time ago).

Comment: @onomatomaniak As Barrie points out, OP's '3 rules' should really have 'about a longer state / process that was 'interrupted' by a shorter action / event'.

Comment: A big thanks to all of you but @FumbleFingers: Does the past progressive really imply a connection to the present? I've always thought that's what the present perfect (progressive) is there for. Could you explain your line of thought a little further please?

Comment: @Juro: Consider a scenario where you answer the doorbell and it turns out to be a friend you haven't seen for years. Sure, you could say *"What a surprise! I thought about you only yesterday!"*. But I think most people would say *"I was thinking about you only yesterday!"*, which to me (possibly by association with present perfect) makes a stronger link between *then* and *now*. But I wouldn't take it to imply a *general* principle - it's just a slight nuance in certain contexts (including yours, I feel). The "extended period" nuance is pretty irrelevant here, of course.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for this little extra example. I normally just speak/write by instinct and don't really think about why or what EXACTLY I was stressing or something. Only if I really want to stress a certain aspect I think about it and then choose an appropriate tense. I guess one shouldn't be too obsessed about grammar if there's so little difference in meaning in some cases. Anyway, judging by your really useful explanation/example I assume that using either tense wouldn't cause misunderstandings. It just comes down to what's more natural/commonly used. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @Juro: Don't take this the wrong way, but I think questions like this are probably best asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Some people object to being classed as "learners" if they're actually native speakers (and I'd have to say if you're *not* a native speaker your command of English is very good! :), but my own feeling is that if people are asking about "correct" usage, *in that context* they ***are*** effectively learners...

Comment: ...note that I myself am active on both sites. I'm not saying your question *shouldn't* have been asked here, but it's close enough to the "cusp point" that I haven't voted one way or the other (whereas if it had been asked on ELL instead, I think I'd have upvoted it). Whatever - I look forward to you posting more questions, on whichever site you think is best.

Answer (score 1):

The past progressive construction is used here because it emphasises a state that continued over time, however brief. The past tense, by contrast, describes an event or action that occurred at a particular time in the past, but it does not emphasise its continuing nature in the way that the present progressive does.

The same applies to your second example. The past progressive emphasises the fact that the talking extended over a period of time. *That's what I talked about* would not be at all appropriate in this context, because it views the action as a single past event that is over and done with.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I greatly appreciate that. You really helped me with your explanation of things. :)